# How to fill MS Word template using Java language?

Tags: java, ms-word

I am creating an application in Java, in which I want to generate a MS Word document from a template. I have prepared a template but I have no idea how to fill the fields in the document.

Is there a library that I could use to fill the fields in the template?

Comment: We need a bit more information. What are you writing the application with? What is the template like? etc.

Comment: I am looking for library which allows me to fill fields in template using variables. I'm creating this program in Java SE.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Apache Poi](https://poi.apache.org/).   Poi is an API for Microsoft documents. You can do operations like create, write etc.

Answer (score 1):

[document-generation](http://www.slideshare.net/plutext/document-generation-2012osdcsydney) is an overview of approaches.

To which should be added, the possibility of doing it as XHTML, then converting to docx.